# Adding CASE to SQL INSERT query with placeholders

Tags: sql, sqlite, case

I have the following in a small Python program

```
def insert_data(self, timestamp, temperature, humidity):
    self.cursor.execute("""
      INSERT INTO sensor_data(timestamp, temperature, humidity)
      VALUES (?,?,?)""",(timestamp, temperature,humidity))
    self.conn.commit()
```

I have added a column to the database called "freezing".

I would like to modify the insert statement to use a `CASE` such that when the temperature is <= 32 the freezing column gets the value "freezing" and otherwise gets "not freezing".

I'm generally clear on the use of CASE statements directly, but not sure about their use with placeholders like this.

full disclosure: this is part of a homework assignment on using `CASE` statements. There's more to it, so it's not like I'm asking you to do to my homework!  But the solution has to use a `CASE`...

Comment: I don't see any relevance to the insert statement here it sounds like you need a [computed column](https://www.sqlite.org/gencol.html)

Comment: I want to store the value in the column "freezing" so that it can be accessed later

Comment: What about having a computed column doesn't work? Its definitely *not* a good idea to insert two physical values that imply the same thing - someone could update the temperature bit not the *freezing* column then you have a data discrepancy. A computed column mitigates that. Also, a column named *freezing* probably needs a Yes or No value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can directly integrate the CASE statement into the VALUES section of your INSERT query and it will check the condition for the temperature and return either "freezing" or "not freezing" based on the temperature value you're inserting :

```
def insert_data(self, timestamp, temperature, humidity):
    self.cursor.execute("""
      INSERT INTO sensor_data(timestamp, temperature, humidity, freezing)
      VALUES (?, ?, ?, CASE WHEN ? <= 32 THEN 'freezing' ELSE 'not freezing' END)""",
      (timestamp, temperature, humidity, temperature))
    self.conn.commit()
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the best solution would be create this validation in memory then insert the final value into your database.

But if you need to add this validation strictly inside the SQL query, you could something like this:

```
def insert_data(self, timestamp, temperature, humidity):
    self.cursor.execute("""
      INSERT INTO sensor_data(timestamp, temperature, humidity, freezing)
      VALUES (?, ?, ?,
        CASE
            WHEN ? <= 32 THEN 'Freezing'
            ELSE 'Not Freezing'
        END
      )""", (timestamp, temperature, humidity, temperature))
    self.conn.commit()
```